# How to connect an azure logic app to a shared calendar

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a countdown api, it's almost embarrassingly simple. When an http request is received, get the events from a calendar, cut the response down a bit (filter) then return the number of days until the next event (js). (I am also trying to do this with a function app, but [got stuck here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024043/baking-auth-into-an-azure-function-app-whats-the-canonical-way))

[image]

I can connect to one of my own calendars without any problems, but when I try to connect to a shared calendar, I have no luck. I can access the shared calendar using the graph explorer with this url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/calendarName@whereIwork.com.au/events?$select=subject,start` So I know that part of the system works.

I've tried several options for an ID, including the ID from the graph explorer

```
"id": "AAMkADljMGQ0ZjNlLTY1MDktNGFmZi05OTBlLWQyNjE1ZjVlNzUxOQBGAABAAABvxqd01Z8OTK1ajR2m-ahiBwAlvPDp3V3YTK9QFfbU2TzGAABAAAEGAAAlvPDp3V3YTK9QFfbU2TzGAABAABHZAAA=",
```

The name of the calendar, the name with `users/` prepended, and a few other versions:

[image]

What is the correct way to connect to this type of calendar?

Comment: why does it say function app in the title?

Comment: Well spotted, I'm trying both approaches, and the words are whizzing around in my brain

Answer (score 1):

You can use API request to get all events you want too, try the action below : 
[image]

For how to get app id and app secret , pls refer to my [previous post for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024043/baking-auth-into-an-azure-function-app-whats-the-canonical-way/59026976#59026976) .